# Задача по алгоритмам

Tags: c++, алгоритм, функции, рекурсия, координаты

Всем привет. Вот задача :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Главный вопрос - как найти индекс нулевого элемента и что делать если их два. Если найти нулевой индекс задачу можно считать решенной.
Итак что мы имеем :

1. По формулам я вывел что, **h[ n ] = h[ 1 ]*n - h[ 0 ]*(n-1) + n*(n-1)**. Т.е. очень легко найти любой элемент если знаешь **h[ 1 ]**, а **h[ 0 ]** высчитывать не нужно, это высота гирлянды конца А, n - индекс элемента, которого хочешь найти.
2. Если приравнять **h[ n ] = 0**, тогда останутся 2 неизвестные В и n. Я так понимаю, их и нужно найти методом дихотомии. Отсюда **B = (h[ 0 ] * (n-1) - n*(n-1))/n**. Ок. Каким образом находить n?
3. Продолжение второго :[image: введите сюда описание изображения] Получаются такие значения, отрицательные показаны красным, положительные синим.
   Подскажите пжлст как вы видите решение, не нужно реализовывать, я сам все напишу

Comment: По идее n - исходные данные. Сам код такой: bmin = 0, bmax=A. В этом интервале решаем задачу оптимизации

Comment: `692 532.81` - ответ (B): `446113.34`
Правда формулировка в [задаче](https://www.e-olymp.com/ru/problems/876) немного другая

Answer (score 0):

Собственно все что вам нужно, кроме вышеуказанных формул - это сам бинарный поиск. Дело в том, что какой-то формулы, для нахождения `n` нет. Нужно его искать путем перебора, но, так как `n` может быть давольно большим числом, перебор от 0 до самого последнего элемента не эффективен. Просто берете среднее `midle` между `left = 0` и `right = n(max)` и выводите `B`. После этого проверяете в какую сторону надо двигаться? Для этого находите элементы правее и левее вашего нулевого элемена `h[n]`. Если они оба выше 0 (ну или один из них также равен 0), то поздравляю - вы пополи в точку - это тот самый `n`. Но если левый элемент меньше 0, то это означает, что `n` находится левее, так что теперь ищем в диапазоне `left` до `right = midle`. Если наоборот, то в диапазоне `left = midle` до `right`.